# Automatically add List of Abbreviations (totcount and acronym)

Tags: spacing, counters, acronyms

I would like to have a list of abbreviations automatically added if there are abbreviations.

I am using acronym for the abbreviations and am currently trying to count the
`\ac` commands using totcount.

```
\documentclass[english, a4paper, 10pt]{article}

%abbreviations
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

%count acronyms
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{acro_num}
\def\oldac{} \let\oldac=\ac
%FIXME_1: \def\ac{\stepcounter{acro_num}\oldac}

\begin{document}

\section{Document Start}

%list of abbrev
\ifnum\totvalue{acro_num}>0%
\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\fi
\begin{acronym}[12345678]
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  %list of acronyms
  \acro{ABR}{abbreviation}
\end{acronym}
\ifnum\totvalue{acro_num}>0%
\clearpage
\fi


%reset abreviations
\acresetall

%document
\section{Amazing...}

%FIXME_2: \ac{ABR} is working!

Bla bla...

\end{document}
```

**Problem:**
If `FIXME_1` is commented in and `FIXME_2` is commented out, there is a space in the document (looks weird, especially with sections!)

(PS: `\ifnum` around the whole block does not work)

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your redefinition of `\ac` is 'weird' ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the original MWE is, that the `acro_num` count is always zero at the beginning of the document, so the test must fail.

This can be bypassed by storing the value of `acro_num` to a other counter at the end of the document to `.aux` file (within `\AtEndDocument`) and read again at the document startup, in `\AtBeginDocument`

As always with such an approach, **two** runs of (pdf)latex are mandatory...

There is an additional (but not requested) `\listofacronyms` which is intented to show on which page an acronym is used.

```
\documentclass[english, a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%abbreviations
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

%count acronyms
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{acro_num}

\let\oldac=\ac
\renewcommand{\ac}[1]{\stepcounter{acro_num}\oldac{#1}%{
\addcontentsline{lac}{section}{\protect{\textbf{#1}\hspace*{0em}}}%
}%

\newcommand{\ListOfAcronymsname}{List of Acronyms}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofacronyms{%
  \section*{\ListOfAcronymsname}    
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\ListOfAcronymsname}{\MakeUppercase\ListOfAcronymsname}%
    \@starttoc{lac}%
    }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\listofabbreviations}{
\ifnumgreater{\number\value{acro_num}}{0}{%
\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}[12345678]
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  %list of acronyms
  \acro{ABR}{abbreviation}
  \acro{OMG}{Oh my god!}
  \acro{EPR}{Einstein-Rosen-Podolsky}
\end{acronym}
\clearpage
\setcounter{acro_num}{0} % reset the counter
}{%
}%

}%

\newcounter{TotalNumberUsedAcronyms}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\setcounter{TotalNumberUsedAcronyms}{\number\value{acro_num}}}%
}%


\AtBeginDocument{%
\setcounter{acro_num}{\number\value{TotalNumberUsedAcronyms}}
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofabbreviations

\section{Document Start}

%reset abreviations
\acresetall

%document
\section{Amazing...}

\ac{ABR}
\ac{OMG}
\newpage
\ac{EPR}


There are \arabic{acro_num} acronyms, for example \ac{OMG}


Bla bla...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It writes the information about used acronyms into a helper file `\jobname.acr`. It needs several LaTeX runs if the mode changes.

```
\documentclass[english, a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.acr}{\def\haveACRO{0}}   
\immediate\openout15=\jobname.acr\relax
\let\oldac=\ac  
\def\ac{%
   \immediate\write15{\string\gdef\string\haveACRO{1}}\oldac} %
\AtEndDocument{\closeout15}
\begin{document}

\section{Document Start}    
\ifnum\haveACRO>0 \section*{List of Abbreviations} \fi
\begin{acronym}[12345678]
  %list of acronyms
  \acro{ABR}{abbreviation}
  \acro{ANC}{African National Congress}
\end{acronym}

\ifnum\haveACRO>0  \clearpage \fi
\acresetall

\section{Amazing...}
\ac{ABR} is working!
\ac{ANC} too
Bla bla...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, that I reinvented the wheel somehow, since the counter value is already stored somewhere else ;-)

Comment: No! it is not known at the beginning of the document!

Comment: Forget my comment! I thought, that `.acr` would be automatically generated by the package. Why do you prefer to open another file instead of writing to `.aux`? I am just curious, it is not meant as criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the fast answers!

Actually, I was wrong.

**Solution**: The `\ifnum` around the whole block **is** working, it just needs **3 compiling runs**.

**Remark**: The totcount package counts the total number of occurances.
That means, even at the beginning of the document `\total{acro_num}` (and `\totvalue{acro_num}`) is
not 0 (assumed enough compile runs and if there is an `\ac` in the document of course).

PS: the weird redefinition of `\ac` is taken from the documentation of totcount ;-)
(see [totcount docu](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/totcount/totcount.pdf) page 2)

Thanks again.

Working example:

```
\documentclass[english, a4paper, 10pt]{article}

%abbreviations
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

%count acronyms
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{acro_num}
\def\oldac{} \let\oldac=\ac
\def\ac{\stepcounter{acro_num}\oldac}

\begin{document}

\section{Document Start}

%list of abbrev
\ifnum\totvalue{acro_num}>0%
\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}[12345678]
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  %list of acronyms
  \acro{ABR}{abbreviation}
\end{acronym}
\clearpage
\fi


%reset abreviations
\acresetall

%document
\section{Amazing...}

%\ac{ABR} is working!

Bla bla...

\end{document}
```